# How to hide or remove options from jQuery Chosen select dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I would like to hide certain elements from a dropdown that is created using the Chosen plugin.

I have tried removing it:

```
$( 'option:contains("Swatch 1")').remove().trigger("chosen:updated");
```

and just hiding it:

`$( '.chosen-results li:contains("Swatch 1")').css('display,'none');`

But neither works.

See Colours dropdown: http://www.carolineelisa.com/test/wordpress/product/machine/

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 6):

In the original select you need to hide the option.  For example:

```
$('select.chosen-select options:contains("Swatch 1")');
```

Then update the chosen options with:

```
$('select.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

If you have more than one chosen drop down on the page then it probably would be better to use a more specific id or class on that element in the place of $('select.chosen-select').  So your code would become:

```
$('#swatch_select options:contains("Swatch 1")');
$('#swatch_select').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all, because Chosen doesn't support option visibility. And "options" is not a valid tag selector...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jquery snipped to **deselect** and update a chosen ddl that is designated as multiple.  ddlID is the ID of the chosen ddl and ddlValue is the value property of the option.

```
$("#ddlID option[value='" + ddlValue + "']").prop('selected', false);
$("#ddlID").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Answer (score 1):

hide the option and update....

```
$('#button').click(function(){
        $('select#theIDselect > option[value="Swatch 1"]').hide();
        $('#theIDselect').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Small edit of kamijean's code:

```
 $('select.chosen-result option:contains("Swatch 1")').hide();
 $('select.chosen-result').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

so not chosen-select but chosen-result and not options but option

for selecting by values and not title use

```
 $('select.chosen-result option[value=830]').hide();
 $('select.chosen-result').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide with **value** or with **class** name. Check working code here.

```
<select id="dd_option" data-placeholder="Select one..." class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
    <option value="all" selected="selected"> All </option>
    <option  value="mls" class="list_srch"> #MLS Number </option>
    <option  value="zip" class="list_srch"> Zip/Postal </option>
    <option value="title"> Listing Title </option>
    </select>
<button type="button" id="btn_hide_val">Hide with value</button>
<button type="button" id="btn_hide_class">Hide with class</button>
<button type="button" id="btn_unhide">Unhide</button>
<script>
```

```js
$(".chzn-select").chosen();

$('#btn_hide_val').click(function() {

    // Just hide option #MLS Number,  Zip/Postal
    $("#dd_option option[value='mls']").hide();
    $("#dd_option option[value='zip']").hide();
    $("#dd_option").trigger("chosen:updated");
        
});
$('#btn_hide_class').click(function() {

    // Just hide option  #MLS Number,  Zip/Postal
    $("#dd_option option[class='list_srch']").hide();

    $("#dd_option").trigger("chosen:updated");
        
});
  
$('#btn_unhide').click(function() {

    // Just hide option 4
    $("#dd_option option[class='list_srch']").show();
        
    $("#dd_option").trigger("chosen:updated");
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <div id="container">
    <h3>Show/Hide options with value and class</h3>
    <select id="dd_option" data-placeholder="Select one..." class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
        <option value="all" selected="selected"> All </option>
        <option  value="mls" class="list_srch"> #MLS Number </option>
        <option  value="zip" class="list_srch"> Zip/Postal </option>
        <option value="title"> Listing Title </option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />

    <button type="button" id="btn_hide_val">Hide with value</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn_hide_class">Hide with class</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn_unhide">Unhide</button>

  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```